# PDF to PS conversion failing using pdftops command on linux

Tags: pdf, postscript, poppler

While trying to convert the PDF file to PS(Postscript) using pdftops command on RHEL machine, I am getting below error:

pdftops -duplex aa.pdf aa.ps
Syntax Error (30576): 4741 extraneous bytes after segment
Syntax Error (30576): 4741 extraneous bytes after segment
Syntax Error (30576): 4741 extraneous bytes after segment
Syntax Error (30576): 4741 extraneous bytes after segment
Syntax Error (23771): Invalid segment reference in JBIG2 text region
Syntax Error (23771): 852 extraneous bytes after segment

Version Information:
pdftops version 0.43.0
Copyright 2005-2016 The Poppler Developers - http://poppler.freedesktop.org
Copyright 1996-2011 Glyph & Cog, LLC

OS: RHEL 12.3

Anyone knows about this issue and how to fix it?

Comment: JBIG2? What kinda image do you have there in the pdf? With which SW can you display the pdf correctly?

Answer (score 0):

No expert, but I looked around and I saw that adobe can throw an error if there are bytes before %PDF in the header of the pdf file: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/pdf-error-1015-11001-update.html

Perhaps this error is for the same reason? 
pdf2ps is as I understand it a different program from pdftops - maybe this one would work?